# Некорректная работа php-скриптов

Tags: php, mysqli

Перенес свой сайт на другой хостинг и столкнулся с ошибкой **500** на главной странице. Путем проверки кода, выяснил, что из-за кода ниже и выходит эта ошибка.
Код:

```
$total_pages = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM post")->num_rows;

$page = isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
$num_results_on_page = 15;
$num_posts = ceil($total_pages / $num_results_on_page);

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY $order DESC LIMIT ?,?");
$calc_page = ($page - 1) * $num_results_on_page;
$stmt->bind_param('ii', $calc_page, $num_results_on_page);
$stmt->execute(); 
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

Кто-нибудь знает, в чем проблема?
Настройки сервере:

```
Apache  2.4.6-97.el7_9.cloudlinux
MySQL   10.2.36-1.el7.centos
PHP 5.4.16-48.el7.cloudlinux
Perl    5.16.3-297.el7
Kernel  3.10.0-962.3.2.lve1.5.42.el7.x86_64
```

Comment: Смотри логи, там всё написано

Comment: вы бы лучше путем просмотра лога сказали бы в какой именно строке происходит ошибка

Comment: Плохой способ считать записи
$total_pages = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM post")->num_rows;

Comment: @teran **Backend fatal error: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in /index.php on line 495\n**. Та самая строка - $result = **$stmt->get_result();**

Comment: значит запрос возвращает false

Comment: @pgood какую альтернативу предложите?

Comment: SELECT count(*) num_rows FROM post

Comment: @АлексейШиманский не возвращает. во-первых до этого на это объекте вызывались и другие методы, во-вторых при вызове метода на булевом значении текст ошибки будет соответствующий

Answer (score 0):

В PHP должно быть установлено расширение mysqlnd
https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php#105802

Comment: Уже установлено. Taк же включены mysql и mysqli

Comment: А nd_mysqli включен?

Comment: Невозможно включить расширение PHP 'nd_mysqli' вместе с расширением 'mysqli'. Сначала необходимо отключить 'mysqli'

Comment: сменил версию php на 7.4 там включены mysqlnd и nd_mysqli. Все равно не работает, все равно та же ошибка

Comment: а что возвращает? extension_loaded('mysqlnd')

Comment: Каждый из трех движков mysql может быть сконфигурирован под разные драйвера, возможно mysqli не использует mysqlnd драйвер, пример конфигурирования при компиляции [расширения MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqlnd.install.html): ./configure --with-mysql=mysqlnd --with-mysqli=mysqlnd --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd

Comment: **extension_loaded('mysqlnd')** - это где прописать?

Comment: короче, я написал в поддержку, скинул им всю информацию, пускай сами разбираются и настраивают свои сервера. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: extension_loaded('mysqlnd') - это [функция PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.extension-loaded.php) проверяет загружено ли расширение

Comment: вернуло, что установлено

Comment: Надеюсь поддержка поможет, сообщите плз, если найдете решение , интересно в чем в итоге была проблема

Comment: и я надеюсь. Хорошо, сообщу, конечно, если решат проблему.